# How to get a sticky header on top of scroll table

Tags: html, css, scroll, sticky

I would like the header of my table to stick, so I can see the headings when I scroll to the very bottom of my table. I tried putting #table-scroll just around the table elements, but it didn't work.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkurls/c1eewwas/1/)

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="pagetop">
            <b>Clinical Molecular Incident Reporting System</b>
            <span id="navigation">

                <a href="/search_incidents/">a</a> | 
                <a href="/report_incident/">b</a> | 
                <a href="/resolve_incident/">c</a> |
                <a href="/equipment_search/">d</a>
                <span id="user-info">wyut | <a href="/logout/">logout</a></span>    

            </span>
        </div>


<p>Not only have you successfully logged in, you have also made it to the Search Incidents page using html templates</p>
<div id="table-wrapper">
    <div id="table-scroll">
        <table class="fixed">
            <col width="5%" />
            <col width="15%" />
            <col width="5%" />
            <col width="80%" />
            <thead>
                <tr><th>ID</th><th>Created At</th><th>Category</th><th>Description</th></tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>12</td><td>date</td><td>4</td>
                <td class="left">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>date</td><td>1</td>
                <td class="left">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi archite</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>2</td><td>date</td><td>1</td>
                <td class="left">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happines</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>3</td><td>date</td><td>1</td>
                <td class="left">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>4</td><td>date</td><td>2</td>
                <td class="left">On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, t</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>5</td><td>date</td><td>2</td>
                <td class="left">On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame b</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>6</td><td>date</td><td>2</td>
                <td class="left">blah</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>7</td><td>date</td><td>2</td>
                <td class="left">blah</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>8</td><td>date</td><td>3</td>
                <td class="left">blah</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>9</td><td>date</td><td>3</td>
                <td class="left">blah</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>10</td><td>date</td><td>3</td>
                <td class="left">blah</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>11</td><td>date</td><td>4</td>
                <td class="left">blah</td></tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>13</td><td>date</td><td>4</td>
                <td class="left">blah</td></tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
</body>



/*--------------------------------------------------------------BASE.HTML*/
html,body {font-family: Verdana; font-size: 16px;}

#content {
    width: 90%; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    background-color: #F6F6EF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#pagetop {
    margin: 0 -10px;
    /*width: 100%; default*/
    background-color: #04B4AE; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

#pagetop  a:link {color:#000; text-decoration: none;}  /* unvisited link  */
#pagetop  a:visited {color:#000; text-decoration: none;}  /* visited link    */
#pagetop  a:hover {color:#000; text-decoration: underline;}  /* mouse over link */
#pagetop  a:active {color:#000; text-decoration: none;}  /* selected link   */ 

#navigation{padding-left: 15px;}

#user-info {float: right;}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------SEARCH_INCIDENTS.HTML*/

table, td, th { width=100%; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { padding: 2px; }
.fixed td{text-align:center;}

thead{ background-color: #04B4AE; }
tbody tr:hover{ background:#E6E6E6; }
#table-wrapper { position:relative; }
#table-scroll { height:500px; overflow:auto; margin-top:20px; }

table.fixed .left{text-align:left;}
table.fixed { table-layout:fixed; }
table.fixed td { overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out : http://www.bootply.com/JnOYtO9xzn

**HTML** :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>
            Fixed Header Scrolling Table 
          </h4>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-fixed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-xs-2">#</th><th class="col-xs-8">Name</th><th class="col-xs-2">Points</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">1</td><td class="col-xs-8">Mike Adams</td><td class="col-xs-2">23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">2</td><td class="col-xs-8">Holly Galivan</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">3</td><td class="col-xs-8">Mary Shea</td><td class="col-xs-2">86</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">4</td><td class="col-xs-8">Jim Adams</td><td>23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">5</td><td class="col-xs-8">Henry Galivan</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">6</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bob Shea</td><td class="col-xs-2">26</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">7</td><td class="col-xs-8">Andy Parks</td><td class="col-xs-2">56</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">8</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bob Skelly</td><td class="col-xs-2">96</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">9</td><td class="col-xs-8">William Defoe</td><td class="col-xs-2">13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">10</td><td class="col-xs-8">Will Tripp</td><td class="col-xs-2">16</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">11</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bill Champion</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-2">12</td><td class="col-xs-8">Lastly Jane</td><td class="col-xs-2">6</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm checking it out.  I'm not following the '>' in the css.

Comment: you mean the meaning of  ' > ' in the css??

Answer (score 0):

You can create two table something like this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Created At</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Description</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
<--! and here table with tbody tag which you can scroll-->
<table>
  <tbody>
   <--! your data -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

here i am add my [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wLt9fs0y/) and you can see how does it work

Comment: does it need to be a hack to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#table-scroll { height: 100px; width: 100%; overflow: auto; margin-top: 40px; }
th { line-height: 0; }
th div { position: absolute; margin-top: -40px; line-height: 40px; }
```

```html
<p>Not only have you successfully logged in, you have also made it to the Search Incidents page using html templates</p>
<div id="table-scroll">
  <table class="fixed">
    <col width="5%" />
    <col width="15%" />
    <col width="15%" />
    <col width="70%" />
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><div>ID</div></th><th><div>Created At</div></th><th><div>Category</div></th><th><div>Description</div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td><td>date</td><td>4</td>
        <td class="left">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>date</td><td>1</td>
        <td class="left">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi archite</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td><td>date</td><td>1</td>
        <td class="left">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happines</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td><td>date</td><td>1</td>
        <td class="left">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td><td>date</td><td>2</td>
        <td class="left">On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, t</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td><td>date</td><td>2</td>
        <td class="left">On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td><td>date</td><td>2</td>
        <td class="left">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td><td>date</td><td>2</td>
        <td class="left">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td><td>date</td><td>3</td>
        <td class="left">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td><td>date</td><td>3</td>
        <td class="left">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td><td>date</td><td>3</td>
        <td class="left">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td><td>date</td><td>4</td>
        <td class="left">blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td><td>date</td><td>4</td>
        <td class="left">blah</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>   
  </table>
</div>
<p>Not only have you successfully logged in, you have also made it to the Search Incidents page using html templates</p>
```